# Websphere that comes with RAD

Tags: websphere

We have some of our Java applications running over WebSphere 5.1 at work. I'm in the process of trying to get my development environment set up.

Thus far I am thinking...

Spring STS
Eclipse Developer tools for WebSphere Application Server version 7.0 
WebSphere Application Server 7.0 Developers Edition

I believe Websphere 7.0 should be okay because we are using J2EE 1.3.

I did however manage to get my hands on a trial version of RAD with came shipped with WebSphere Application Server 5.1 however we don't plan to buy a license.

Can anyone give me advice as to whether I will be breaching licensing agreements if I rip out WAS 5.1 which came shipped with RAD? Is the version that came shipped with RAD a developer edition?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're concerned about licensing, go ask your manager or team lead. The way IBM handles licensing can vary greatly between products, your company's relationship with IBM and how you initially purchased the product. Someone within your company should know about the license agreement your company has with IBM.

I know that for my current project we can have an instance of WAS running on our local machines for free. Every time we need to setup a new shared environment, like Test or Production, that's when we need to pay for a new license. That may be the same situation for you but that's not something anyone here can really answer.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I wasn't aware the licensing agreement was different between customers.

Comment: I can't say that the agreement is different, but the main point should be that licensing with IBM isn't always straight forward and you should talk to someone in your organization that knows it or can find the answer for you.